# Performing a GROUP_BY after an ORDER_BY in Eloquent

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a situation where I need to

1. **order** my results based on an order by logic
2. **group** by to only get the first result after the order.

I have two tables `objects` and `object_versions`

Each object can have several versions and the two tables are linked through

`objects.id = object_versions.id`

My order logic is the following `abs(object_versions.size - $someNumber)`
This works great for ordering the issue is without the **group by** I still get all the other versions in the results. See the scenarios and the fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a967b/23

---

**Query 1 (correct results but without the grouping)**

---

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
  objects.id as object_id, 
  object_versions.id as object_versions_id, 
  object_versions.size as object_versions_size
FROM objects
INNER JOIN object_versions ON objects.id = object_versions.id
ORDER BY abs(object_versions.size - 1000) ASC;
```

**ELOQUENT**

```
Object::join('object_versions', 'objects.id', '=', 'object_versions.id')
->orderByRaw("abs(width - ?) ASC", [1000])
->select('objects.id as object_id', 'object_versions.id as object_versions_id', 'object_versions.size as object_versions_size')->get();
```

**RESULTS**

```
id  id  size
1   1   800
2   2   800
2   2   400
1   1   400
2   2   300
1   1   300
```

---

**Query 2 (bad results produced with the grouping before the order)**

---

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
  objects.id as object_id, 
  object_versions.id as object_versions_id, 
  object_versions.size as object_versions_size
FROM objects
INNER JOIN object_versions ON objects.id = object_versions.id
GROUP BY object_id
ORDER BY abs(object_versions.size - 1000) ASC;
```

**ELOQUENT**

```
Object::join('object_versions', 'objects.id', '=', 'object_versions.id')
->orderByRaw("abs(width - ?) ASC", [1000])
->groupBy("objects.id")
->select('objects.id as object_id', 'object_versions.id as object_versions_id', 'object_versions.size as object_versions_size')->get();
```

**RESULTS**

```
id  id  size
1   1   300
2   2   300
```

---

**Query 3 (correct results with the grouping after the order but don't see how to produce this in eloquent)**

---

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    objects.id as object_id, 
    object_versions.id as object_versions_id, 
    object_versions.size as object_versions_size
  FROM objects
  INNER JOIN object_versions ON objects.id = object_versions.id
  ORDER BY abs(object_versions.size - 1000) ASC
) as result 
GROUP BY object_id;
```

**ELOQUENT**
I don't see how to do this...

**RESULTS**

```
1   1   800
2   2   800
```

Comment: Your use of `select *` in a `group by` query -- especially one that depends on the ordering in a subquery -- is specifically documented to produce indeterminate results (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).  Use proper SQL and your code should work.

Comment: Thanks for the info Gordon but actually I'm not using a * in my app, I added it here as a shorthand and did not realize it was not permitted. Either way in my real app the outer select replicates the same fields defined in the subquery so that' doesn't' change the problem much.

Comment: It is not specifically the `*` . . . it is any column that is not in the `group by` list (and that is not the argument to an aggregation column).  You get "indeterminate" results for these columns.